# Pass expression to initializer

Tags: c#

I would like to pass an expression that represents a variable to used when instantiating an object.

Instead of:

```cs
class MyObject : IMyInterface { ... }

var list = db.MyObjects.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).ToList();
var anotherList = list.Select(x => new AnotherObject() { 
  Id = x.Id,
  Value = x.Value
});
```

I would like to make this so that a list of objects of `IMyInterface` can be transformed into another type of list (AnotherObject as example) using defined expressions as so:

```cs
var list = db.MyObjects
  .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
  .ToAnotherObjectList(x => x.Id, x => x.Value);

...

public static List<AnotherObject> ToAnotherObjectList<T>(
  this IEnumerable<IMyInterface> list, 
  Expression id, 
  Expression value)
{
    return list.Select(x => new AnotherObject() { Id = id, Value = value }).ToList();
}
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this.  I know I can use reflection to create objects and set properties by a string but I'm not sure how to pass expressions.

## UPDATE

Well, I thought I'd have to do some reflection but it's simpler than what I was thinking.  Here's my solution that works in IRL.

```
public static IEnumerable<AnotherObject> ToAnotherObject<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> list,
    Func<T, int> getId,
    Func<T, string> getValue,
    Func<T, bool> getSelected = null)
    where T : IMyInterface
{
    return list.Select(x => new AnotherObject {
        Display = getValue(x),
        Id = getId(x),
        Selected = getSelected != null && getSelected(x),
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Func<TInput,TReturn>` for that. For example:

```
public static List<AnotherObject> ToAnotherObjectList<T>(
  this IEnumerable<T> list, 
  Func<T, int> getId,
  Func<T, object> getValue)
{
    return list.Select(x => new AnotherObject() { Id = getId(x), Value = getValue(x) }).ToList();
}
```

Call:

```
list.ToAnotherObjectList(i => i.Id, i=> i.Value);
```

In this example I used Funcs with one parameter (of type T) and return type int/object.

Comment: Well I thought it would be more complicated than that.  This clarifies things further.  Thanks, this works for me.  I've also updated the top to be very close to what I'm actually using while constraining `T` by `where T : IMyInteface`.